# Pass data between OnGet to OnPost in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, razor-pages

i have a razor page with OnGet and OnPost methods :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Page();
}
```

then the form appear for the user and the user fill the data and post it o OnPost(), my question is if i have data in the OnGet() method, and i need to pass it with the form to OnPost() method, what is the best solution ?

for example : i want to pass the id i got in the OnGet method to OnPost method, what is the best way ?

i already have a solution to use input with type hidden to pass the id, but i want to see if there is any better methods.

Comment: You can include it in a `<form>` post, cookies, or session.

Comment: If you have a form already, the simplest way would be to take the hidden field approach.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `<form>` simply include a hidden input field like that:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.id" name="id"/>
```